# Ubuntu 21.10 flashes from live USB and then crashes

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 21.10, amd-ryzen

**System info**

- Laptop model: Victus by HP Laptop 16-e0xxx
- RAM: AMD ryzen 7 5800H (16G)
- Graphics card: nvidia rtx 3050
- Current OS: Windows 10
- Desired OS: Ubuntu 21.10
- Program used to create the live USB: RUFUS

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 21.10 from a live USB to install it. It flashes, shows me the background picture and then crashes and the computer starts Windows.

From what another user has told me I had debian installed on one of the partitions of my laptop *(I don´t remember doing this)*, deleted that partition and the computer is trying to load the GRUB bootloader instead of the USB. (I have no technical knowledge so I'm going to assume that´s right)
I found on the boot folder a file named grubx64.efi, that I deleted as I was told that it was conflicting.

I don´t think that it is an image problem as I have rewritten the USB like 5 times.

I really hope that someone can help me as in this point I´m getting really frustrated with this, and I´m at the brink of going to a technical support shop, though I would prefer to manage it "myself" and save the money and pride.

I´m not as tech savvy as some users here so please try to make it simple:)

Thank you for your patience and time.

The message that appears when I try to boot Ubuntu from the live USB:

```
[ 0.2551641 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ISB.PCIO.GPP1.W LAN), AE_NOT FOUND (20210331/dswload2-162)

[ 0.2551771 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220) 

[ 0.2555611 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [/_SB.PC10.GPP0.VGA], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 

[ 0.2555641 ACPI Error: AE ALREADY EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)

[ 0.255567] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.G PPO.HDAU), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 

[ 0.255569] ACPI Error : AE ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)
```

Comment: Did you change the UEFI to boot from USB? If it is booting ```grub``` than it is probably booting from the harddisk. Enter your UEFI with the appropiat FSomething key (I don't know what motherboard you have, so cannot tell you which Function-key is needed). In UEFI change the ```boot sequence```. USB first, than harddisk. Exit with saving the settings.    Did you make the drive with the proper settings in Rufus? (That is why i use Ventoy, no settings needed and the posibility to put more iso's on it.)    Did you check the integrity of the written medium?

Comment: I changed the boot order on the BIOS as you told me, it didn´t work. I got some errors that are edited into the original post, because they are too long for a comment . I´m pretty sure that I had the right settings on RUFUS, I followed a tutorial I found on youtube that worked with my previous system.

Comment: I found an interesting thing abojut AMD CPU/GPU here. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462612. Why don't try 20.04 LTS? Maybe that will install without issues. And after a month upgrade to 22.04 (release end of April). Your Windows ia still working, right? Not an answer to what is happening, but maybe a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It didn´t work though, tried to boot the 20.04 LTS and didn´t work, got the exact same errors. Just to clarify, on the link to ubuntuforums that you have sent me, I found someting about enabling IOMMU, this means enabling the possiblity of multiple virtual machines on the BIOS right? As I didn´t find that exact settting. If it´s the VM´s case, I´m affraid that didn´t work either.

Comment: There are many youtube videos on the ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND-error. Just search for ```ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND```. They might help, preferably seen on another device, so you can do the things as you watch. I hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED*

I was able to boot ubuntu with safe graphics and load the Ubuntu's instalation tool. I installed 20.04 lts, as 21.10 had some hardware support problems, And it worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help guys, I will for sure come back to you.